# Calculate the Fourier Transform of the function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have to calculate the Fourier transform of the function $f(x)=sgn(x) e^{-a |x|}, a \geq 0$. After that I have to take the limit $ a \rightarrow 0$ to calculate the Fourier transform of the sign function $f(x)=sgn(x)$.
$$$$
I have found that the Fourier transform of the function $f(x)=sgn(x) e^{-a |x|}$ is: $$\widetilde{f}(k)=- \frac{2ik}{a^2+k^2}$$
Is this correct???
$$$$
Then to calculate the Fourier transform of the sign function, can I take the limit $ a \rightarrow 0$ at $\widetilde{f}(k)=- \frac{2ik}{a^2+k^2}$?? Or do I have to calculate the integral from the beginning??

Comment: It does depend which definition you use for the Fourier transform.  But your answer to the first part does look correct.  For the second part, I think you are meant to let $a\to\infty$ without recalculating the whole thing.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Do you mean $a \rightarrow 0$?? So is the Fourier transform of the sign function $$-\frac{2ik}{k^2}=-\frac{2i}{k}$$??

Comment: Oops yes, and yes.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith In Wolfram the result is: $$\frac{i \sqrt(\frac{2}{\pi})}{k}$$ Why is it like that??

Comment: Because the definition of Fourier transform isn't unique.  There are various $\sqrt{2\pi}$'s and minus signs that differ from book to book.  Notice that Wolfram's is a multiplicative factor of $-1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ different from your answer.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Aha! Ok!!! But my result also correct?? right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Great!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)